# Gmaps4rails - Map throwing JS error on first load when JSON == "[]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, geocoding, gmaps4rails

I am using the geocoder gem's `.nearby` method to query my DB and return nearby location objects.

Question 1: When loading the map for the first time, no markers are passed to the JS, and it does not load the map.  How can I fix this issue without loading a marker?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
Gmaps.map.map_options.detect_location = true;
Gmaps.map.map_options.center_on_user = true;
Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.markers = ; // BLOWS UP HERE
Gmaps.map.markers_conf.list_container = "markers_list";
Gmaps.map.create_markers();
Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
Gmaps.map.callback();
};
Gmaps.oldOnload = window.onload;
 window.onload = function() { Gmaps.triggerOldOnload(); Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
</script>`
```

Question 2: When user searches and no nearby results are available to their search, how to recover from this just showing a random location (right now it loads the middle of the ocean).

Question 3: When user searches and no nearby results are available, can I show nearby locations to their current location using browser geolocation (I know it's not supported in all browsers).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4075215

Comment: Crap. What version do you use?

Comment: gmaps4rails 1.5.6 and rails 3.2.8 and ruby 1.9.3p194

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

There is no bug in the gem.

This line of yours makes javascript cry:

```
@json = nil
```

Indeed `nil` isn't valid json.

You should do:

```
@json = [].to_json
```

**Answer 2**

If your query doesn't return anything, Make another one to get a random object. Can't see any problem there.

**Answer 3**

Geolocation from browser is included in the gem, you even have a callback on success. [See code](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/1.x/app/assets/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee#L91). But you'll have to write your own javascript fitting your own logic.

Comment: **Answer 1**
So I've used `@json = [].to_json`, but now this loads the middle of the ocean, and returns the notice in the sidebar that says `No dealers found`.  How can I edit this message ONLY for this first load case so it says `Search above to find dealers` or something of the like.

**Answer 2**
But this still places a marker, and adds it to the sidebar, and is very confusing behavior for the user.  I almost think just showing the middle of the ocean is a better solution, lol.  Thoughts?

Comment: You can use the `Gmaps.map.callback` to adapt the map behavior to your situation. You can simply do what you want! Your controller knows the exact situation, tell your view.